# Post an image on instagram using Oauth2 - PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, instagram

All I want to post **an image** on the instagram using Oauth2 & PHP pretty similar like wall post for Facebook and Tweet post for Twitter like:

User click on **share on Instagram** button from my website, they redirect to the Instagram app approval page, they approve and the image gets posted on their account.

I have searched almost entire internet for this requirement. But I didn't get exact code to achieve this.

I have already checked these:

https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API

https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Some people says that it is not possible, Instagram doesn't allow that.

So all I want is a clear answer whether is it possible or not? If yes then how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Clear answer

**It's not possible and not official in any way**. All the Unofficial APIs / packages / libraries... whaterver you might find are barely tentatives of reverse engineering of the traffic generated by the Instagram App.

So they might work for a while, but then Instagram will block them.

Think about it. If there's somewhere an official way to upload stuff to instagram there will be a lot of alternative apps and spammers using it.

If you don't believe me, [check the official API documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/). There's no reference to the upload of pictures.

Comment: Napolux Thanks. I also think the same way.

Comment: Napolux, I would like to wait and hear if someone else has some other point of views. If I won't get any other answers in the next few days then I'll definitely accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post istagram image with caption using facebook api(business account - without login) 
ref - https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk

<?php 
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__.'/src/Facebook/');
require_once(__DIR__.'/src/Facebook/autoload.php');
    $instaData = [
                 'image_url' => 'image_url',
                 'caption' => htmlspecialchars('your message')
                 ];     
$pageAccessToken ='your access token';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => 'fb_app_id',
 'app_secret' => 'app secrect',
 'default_graph_version' => 'v12.0',
]);
try {
 $response = $fb->post('INSTA_PAGE_ID/media/?', $instaData, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
$creation_id = json_decode($graphNode);
$publish_image = [
                 'creation_id' => intval($creation_id->id)
                ];
try {
 $response1 = $fb->post('INSTA_PAGE_ID/media_publish/?', $publish_image, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($response1); echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This method works, it should be accepted as the correct answer (since the change of IG API). One thing to simplify, just use `'creation_id' => $graphNode['id']`.